# Flex: access dynamically added RicheEditableText in other function

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, mxml, red5

When I click on a userlist, the function `addTab` is triggered:

```
private var counter:int = 0;

public function addTab():void {
    var new vBox:VBox = new VBox();
    var textBox:RichEditableText = new RichEditableText();
    var nameEm:String = "dynamicTextBox" + counter;
    textBox.id = nameEm;
    counter++;
    var textFlow:TextFlow = new TextFlow();
    vbox.addChild(textFlow);
    vbox.addChild(textBox);
    tabNavigator.add(vBox);
}
```

In another function, I would like to add Rich Text to the newly created TextBox, but I can not access it.

I tried `getChildByName(vbox)` and `vbox.getChildByName(textBox)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: getChildByName takes a string argument. You need to set the .name property of the textBox and then search for that name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get childbyname assigned a name to richeditable text and if you want to get it by counter then give name to vbox also, as in the sample here:

```
private var counter:int = 0;

public function addTab():void {
    var new vBox:VBox = new VBox();
    var textBox:RichEditableText = new RichEditableText();
    var nameEm:String = "dynamicTextBox" + counter;
    textBox.id = nameEm;
    vBox.name=nameEm;
    textBox.name=nameEm;
    counter++;
    var textFlow:TextFlow = new TextFlow();
    vbox.addChild(textFlow);
    vbox.addChild(textBox);
    tabNavigator.add(vBox);
}
```

If you know the index then

```
var vb:VBox = tabNavigator.getChildByName("dynamicTextBox"+index) as VBox;
var txt:RichEditableText=vb.getChildByName("dynamicTextBox"+index) as VBox;
```

So this will give you RichEditableText.

Or if you want to get access just after adding in to tab then return RichEditableText from the `addtab` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out, I have been breaking my head over this for over 2 full days!!

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on my comment, the idea is that you do something like this:

```
private var counter:int = 0;

public function addTab():void {
    var new vBox:VBox = new VBox();
    vBox.name = "dynVbox" + counter;
    var textBox:RichEditableText = new RichEditableText();
    textBox.name = "dynamicTextBox" + counter;

    var textFlow:TextFlow = new TextFlow();
    textFlow.name = "dynamicTextFlow" + counter;
    vbox.addChild(textFlow);
    vbox.addChild(textBox);
    tabNavigator.add(vBox);
    counter++;
}
```

Now, outside this function, you just need to know the counter number of the vBox you want. So for example:

```
var myBox = tabNavigator.getChildByName('dynVbox'+ 32).getChildByName('dynamicTextBox'+32)
```

Without seeing more of your code, I don't know if this is the best way to go about it, but if you want to mark your boxes with some dynamically generated name and look them up later, this will work

[Example documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29)